# How Row Key is designed in Hbase

Tags: database, hbase

I am writing a program that converts an RDBMS into HBase. I selected a sequential entity as a row key like Employee ID (1,2,3....)but i read it somewhere that row key shouldn't be a sequential entity. My question is why selecting a sequential row key is not recommended. what are the design prospects associated for doing the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although sequential rowkeys allow faster scans, it becomes a problem after a certain point as it causes undesirable `RegionServer hotspotting` during read/write time. By its default behavior Hbase stores rows with similar keys to the same region. It allows faster range scans. So if rowkeys are sequential all of your data will start going to the same machine causing uneven load on that machine. This is called as RegionServer Hotspotting and is the main motivation behind not using sequential keys. I'll take "writes" to explain the problem here.

When records with sequential keys are being written to HBase all writes hit one Region.  This would not be a problem if a Region was served by multiple RegionServers, but that is not the case – each Region lives on just one RegionServer. Each Region has a pre-defined maximal size, so after a Region reaches that size it is split in two smaller Regions.  Following that, one of these new Regions takes all new records and then this Region and the RegionServer that serves it becomes the new hotspot victim.  Obviously, this uneven write load distribution is highly undesirable because it limits the write throughput to the capacity of a single server instead of making use of multiple/all nodes in the HBase cluster.

You can find a very good explanation of the problem along with its solution [here](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/).

You might also find this [page](http://hbase.apache.org/book/rowkey.design.html) helpful, which shows us how to design rowkeys efficiently.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly because sequentially increasing row keys will be written to the same region, and not evenly distributed in terms of writes. If you have a write-intensive application, it makes sense to have some randomness in your row-key.

[This is a great explanation (with graphics)](http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/) on why a sequentially increasing row-key is a bad idea for HBase.

Comment: Under what circumstances data gets written to a different cluster?By "same cluster" do you mean "same server"??

Comment: Sorry yes. Updating answer now.